# Sort list of dictionaries by key using a custom sort function

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries I wish to sort in python by a key 'id'.

```
items = [{'id' : 883},{'id' : 547},{'id' : 898},{'id' : 30},{'id' : 883}]
```

I wish to sort them in a specific order based on this sorting order given:

```
[30, 883, 547, 898]
```

How would I go about doing this in python3?

Comment: What is the sorting logic in this example?

Comment: What logic exactly would possibly yield that ordering? (`30 883 547 898`) None of the answers attempt to answer the question since they ignore your strange and unexplained desired order, as @janos points out.  EDIT: Brendan's does respect the order you ask for.

Comment: Obviously this is an example of a [zig-zag sort](https://medium.com/@domarp/sorting-an-array-of-integers-into-a-zig-zag-pattern-c59507915cb). (joking, I think)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `key` argument and a list with the custom sorting order.

```
sort_order = [30, 883, 547, 898]
items.sort(key=lambda d: sort_order.index(d['id']))
```

Using @Sphinx 's recommendation, you could index the list beforehand for some added speed improvement `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`

```
sort_order_index = {val: i for i, val in enumerate(sort_order)}
items.sort(key=lambda d: sort_order_index.get(d['id'], 0))
```

Comment: Huh, so this is what he wanted? Nice python-fu, +1

Comment: use `sort_order={}` instead of `sort_order=[]` will be better? `sort_order.index(id)` should be slower than dict[id]

Comment: I don't like using `index` very much because of its `O(n)` aspect

Comment: @Sphinx: replacing the list by a set destroys the initial order of items in sort_order, so the algorithm fails. `Watch the difference between `print( [30, 883, 547, 898])` and `print({30, 883, 547, 898})`

Comment: @Sphinx Good idea

Comment: make it `sort_order_index.get(d['id'],0)` so items not in the sort_order list don't make your comparator crash by comparing with `None`

Answer (score 0):

You can try without loop in one line something like this:

```
items = [{'id' : 883},{'id' : 547},{'id' : 898},{'id' : 30},{'id' : 883}]

sorting_order=[30, 883, 547, 898]

print(sorted(items,key=lambda x:sorting_order.index(x['id'])))
```

output:

```
[{'id': 30}, {'id': 883}, {'id': 883}, {'id': 547}, {'id': 898}]
```